# How do i "connect" array elements with other variables?

Tags: c++

So, I got this project that my teacher gave me and im pretty new so I came accross a little problem. Basically, I need to input a few citites and their population, and I need to output them in order from the one with the most people to the one with least people in it. I used structures to store information about each city and now I don't know how can I sort of "connect" population to each city if you know what I mean. Thank you!

This is what it looks like, and to people that didn't understand the question, I got the city population and sorted it from the highest to the lowest, and now I want to display the name of the city with it's population next to it but I don't know how can I now add them together.

```
struct city
{
    string name;
    int population;
}cityVar[10];

int main()
{
    // Input
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> cityVar[i].name;
        cin >> cityVar[i].population;
    }

    int i, j;
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (cityVar[i].population < cityVar[j].population)
            {
                temp = cityVar[i].population;
                cityVar[i].population = cityVar[j].population;
                cityVar[j].population = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << cityVar[i].population << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow ain't an homework service. Please provide the code you already have as this is more uniform that English text

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you might be looking for [`std::unordered_map` or `std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Either you dig into `std::map` or you search for `std::sort`.

Comment: If you didn't store the population in the structure you defined, where did you store it? If you did, the solution you're looking for is to sort your cities by population, not "connect" them.

Comment: A piece of advice: the next time you will ask a question here, show us your attempt at it, in the form of code that compiles. Good luck!

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Provide a some code showing what you have so far. Preferably a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap the full object, there are many ways to do this but depending on what you've been taught you'll need to be careful of which method you use. This is by no means an exhaustive list, I've only shown the simplest I can think of....

The simplest method (but requires another two lines) and depends on the data structure, so use a temp city instead of a temp int.

```
struct city temp;
:
:
:
   if (cityVar[i].population < cityVar[j].population)
   {
       temp.population = cityVar[i].population;
       temp.name = cityVar[i].name;

       cityVar[i].population = cityVar[j].population;   
       cityVar[i].name = cityVar[j].name;

       cityVar[j].population = temp.population;
       cityVar[j].name = temp.name;
   }
```

Another method would be to use a list of pointers for the sorted list

```
int main()
{
  struct city *cityVarSorted[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // initialise list to point to current structs
  {
    cityVarSorted[i] = &cityVar[i];
  }
  :
  :
  struct city *temp;
  :
  if (cityVarSorted[i]->population < cityVarSorted[j]->population)
  {
     temp = cityVarSorted[i]; // we're swapping the pointer now and not the individual members
     cityVarSorted[i] = cityVarSorted[j];
     cityVarSorted[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

of course that's if you've been taught pointers. You need to know how it works so you are able to explain it

Answer (score 3):

You do not *connect* two variables. You group them together when they belong to the same concept.

In this specific case I suggest you to create an abstraction for a `city` by creating a `struct`, and  instruct it on how to to compare itself to other cities based solely (in this case) on the population.

You can do this by implementing the `operator<`

```
struct city{
    unsigned population

    bool operator<(const city& c1){
         return this.population < c1.population;
     }
};
```

You can then add your element into an array or even better a `std::vector` and sort them using `std::sort`.

Since this sounds like an homework, I will leave the rest to you. You should be able to continue on your own from here.

Comment: not exactly the way data encapsulation would recomend it, but i will do the trick

Comment: @skratchi.at this is the simplest and most intuitive way I can think at this moment.

Comment: @skratchi.at absolutely no offense taken =)

Answer (score 1):

You lost the "connection" because you only swapped the populations when you should have swapped the entire cities:

```
city temp = cityVar[i];
cityVar[i] = cityVar[j];
cityVar[j] = temp;
```

Or, as we often write it

```
std::swap(cityVar[i], cityVar[j]);
```